# Where does Spark actually persist RDDs on disk?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using persist on different storage levels, but I found no difference on performance when I was using `MEMORY_ONLY` and `DISK_ONLY`.

I think there might be something wrong with my code... Where can I find the persisted RDDs on disk so that I can make sure they were actually persisted?

Comment: Is there enough RAM space to persist the RDD?

Comment: Actually yes. But I am benchmarking Spark so I would like it to persist only on disk to see the difference.

Comment: SPARK_WORKER_DIR or SPARK_LOCAL_DIR are properties which tells where spark is caching on disk

Answer (score 8):

As per the doc:

> `spark.local.dir` (by default `/tmp`)
>
> Directory to use for "scratch" space in Spark, including map output files and RDDs that get stored on disk. This should be on a fast, local disk in your system. It can also be a comma-separated list of multiple directories on different disks. NOTE: In Spark 1.0 and later this will be overriden by SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS (Standalone, Mesos) or LOCAL_DIRS (YARN) environment variables set by the cluster manager.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible reasons for your observation:

- RDDs are [persisted in a lazy fashion](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations), therefore, to make it work you should call an action(e.g. `count()`) on it after you call `persist()`
- Even if you make sure the `persist()` happens, the actual data may not write to disk actually, your write method is returned directly after the data is write into [buffer cache](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/buffer-cache.html), therefore, when you read it next to write, it simply return the cached data.

So, Did persist happens?
Did you clear linux `Buffer cache` on each node after persist rdd as `DISK_ONLY`, before operate on it and measure performance?

So what I suggest you to do is:

1. persist rdd as DISK_ONLY, invoke an action(e.g. count()), to make it persist.
2. sleep the application for a few seconds, clear the `cache` of all the worker node during this period
   `sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
3. resume your procedure, and measure the performance of persisted RDD.